# Datatables add a new row with alignment as center

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page with method to create and display a datatable:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
var table;
var socket;
$(document).ready(function() {
          table = $('#example').DataTable();
socket  = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:80');
socket.on('message', function (data) {
var rowNode = table
        .row.add( [ data.ID, data.Name, data.Dispensed, data.Amt, data.Balance, data.PPM, data.Avail] )
        .draw()
        .node();

$( rowNode )
    .css( 'color', 'red' )
    .animate( { color: 'black' } );
    } );
});

</script>
```

The scripts gets called perfectly well when backend scripts in NodeJS sends a message over web socket. But my issue is that the data displayed in the table is not center aligned as in temporary row (new data - color red, old temp data - black):

[image]

Is there a way I can center align all the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding alignment as part of .css in the following block:

```
$( rowNode )
    .css( 'color', 'red';text-align:center )
    .animate( { color: 'black' } );
    } );
```

For more alignment related css properties check this [link](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)